# Serialize a generic object to *.INI text file implementing a custom IFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, ini

Good morning.

I need to **serialize** virtually any kind of serializable **object to an *.INI file**.
I'm trying to implement `IFormatter`, where `void Serialize(Stream, object)` method gets property info from object instance and then writes key/value for primitive types or sections + key/values for complex types.

Take this code as example of objects to serialize.

```
[Serializable]
public class EmployeeList
{
    #region Properties
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

    public string Banana { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Constructors
    public EmployeeList()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
    #endregion


    #region Public Methods
    public void Serialize()
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new IniFormatter();

        using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create("employees.ini"))
        {
            try
            {
                formatter.Serialize(outputStream, this);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}

[Serializable]
public class Employee
{
    #region Properties
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Gender Gender
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Role> Roles
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion


    #region Constructors
    public Employee()
    {
    }
    #endregion
}

[Serializable]
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
}

[Serializable]
public class Role
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    #region Constructors
    public Role()
    {

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Well, everything seemed trivial since I tried to acquire properties name and values by reflection; I continuously get an `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException` when trying to reflect `List<Employee>` (see method `pi.GetValue(obj, null);`, where `pi` is `PropertyInfo`).

This is the code of my `IniFormatter`:

```
public class IniFormatter : IFormatter
{
    #region Properties
    public ISurrogateSelector SurrogateSelector { get; set; }

    public SerializationBinder Binder { get; set; }

    public StreamingContext Context { get; set; }
    #endregion


    #region Constructors
    public IniFormatter()
    {
        Context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All);
    }
    #endregion


    #region IFormatter Members
    public object Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Serialize(Stream serializationStream, object graph)
    {
        var propertyInfos = graph.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(serializationStream);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            if (!propertyInfo.CanRead)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (Attribute.IsDefined(propertyInfo, typeof (NonSerializedAttribute)))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0}={1}", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(graph, null));
            }

            //object/complex types need to recursively call this method until the end of the tree is reached
            else
            {
                var complexType = GetPropertyValue(graph, propertyInfo.Name);
                Serialize(serializationStream, complexType);
            }
        }

        sw.Close();
    }
    #endregion


    public static object GetPropertyValue(object sourceObject, string propertyName)
    {
        if (sourceObject == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        object obj = sourceObject;

        // Split property name to parts (propertyName could be hierarchical, like obj.subobj.subobj.property
        string[] propertyNameParts = propertyName.Split('.');

        foreach (string propertyNamePart in propertyNameParts)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // propertyNamePart could contain reference to specific 
            // element (by index) inside a collection
            if (!propertyNamePart.Contains("["))
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyNamePart, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (pi == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                obj = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
            else
            {
                // propertyNamePart is a reference to specific element 
                // (by index) inside a collection
                // like AggregatedCollection[123]
                // get collection name and element index
                int indexStart = propertyNamePart.IndexOf("[") + 1;
                string collectionPropertyName = propertyNamePart.Substring(0, indexStart - 1);
                int collectionElementIndex = Int32.Parse(propertyNamePart.Substring(indexStart, propertyNamePart.Length - indexStart - 1));
                //   get collection object
                PropertyInfo pi = obj.GetType().GetProperty(collectionPropertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (pi == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                object unknownCollection = pi.GetValue(obj, null);
                //   try to process the collection as array
                if (unknownCollection.GetType().IsArray)
                {
                    object[] collectionAsArray = unknownCollection as Array[];
                    obj = collectionAsArray[collectionElementIndex];
                }
                else
                {
                    //   try to process the collection as IList
                    IList collectionAsList = unknownCollection as IList;
                    if (collectionAsList != null)
                    {
                        obj = collectionAsList[collectionElementIndex];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // ??? Unsupported collection type
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
}
```

I run my tests from a console app, doing this:

```
            Employee employee = new Employee {Name = "Nando", Gender = Gender.Male, Roles = new List<Role> {new Role {Name = "CEO", Value = 1}}};

        EmployeeList employeeList = new EmployeeList();
        employeeList.Banana = "It's delicious!";
        employeeList.Employees.Add(employee);

        employeeList.Serialize();
```

I can get the `Banana` property value (sorry for property name, when I get angry my naming conventions goes crazy), and nothing else.

This is quite a "solve my problem" question, I know, but I cannot find sources where to understand I can completely reflect an object an deal with its properties names and values.
So I ask help from skilled developers to point me out to some sources, I'm going crazy. :-)    Thanks a lot,
Nando

Comment: I finally found C# Visual Studio 2008 sample ObjectDumper, it seems help me a lot: [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Visual-Studio-2008-C-d295cdba/file/46086/1/ObjectDumper.zip).

Comment: Also present a CodePlex page: [ObjectDumper](http://objectdumper.codeplex.com/)